Lambda (prod) and AWS SAM returning different responses from the same function code
I have a live and dev version of the same Lambda function. One is running in Lambda with API Gateway, one is running locally on AWS SAM. I'm using this function to send response:
    sendRes(status: number, body: any) {

        let response = {
            statusCode: status,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PATCH"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        };

        return response;
    };

In Postman - the response from the Lambda prod, comes in tact, this shape:
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PATCH"
    },
    "body": "[]"
}

Also in Postman, the response from my AWS SAM comes with just the body:
[]

Why is this? And how do I fix it so both responses are the same shape? Obviously this has consequences for being able to test live code locally without having if/else statements all over my codebase.
Help appreciated, thanks.

Uhm, wait. Lambda does not play with HTTP at all, the function itself returns just a payload of a well-known shape. It does not tranfer such output over HTTP - headers become HTTP headers, status becomes HTTP status code, and body is the actual body, you see it in postman or curl.

@STerliakov - Lambda through API Gateway, obviously.

So when you call your API Gateway endpoint via postman, you receive {"statusCode": 200...} JSON as body? Your SAM response looks correct, AGW should return the same thing.

Yes exactly. That's the problem

Please show your API Gateway definition, lambda (is sendRes an entrypoint? Is it deployed as image or as source? Have you tried adding logging to verify that this function is indeed called?), and a curl or wget invocation showing this behaviour (or textual verbose export from Postman if it supports such).
